# Assign value to points in a 3D array that are inside an ellipsoid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, geometry

I need to assign value to points in a 3D array that are inside an ellipsoid.
The ellipsoid equation should be something like this:

```
r=b.sin(u)
x=r.cos(v)
y=r.sin(v)
z=a.cos(u).
```

But I think that this is only visual. I already tried something with a mask over a cubic array:

```
a, b = (size-1)/2, (size-1)/2
n = size
r = (size-1)/2

y,x = np.ogrid[-a:n-a, -b:n-b]
mask = x*x + y*y <= r*r        # circle mask

array = np.zeros((n, n, n))
array[mask] = 10
```

But this creates a circle only in x and y which gives me: [image: This]/[image: plots].

It's not a sphere. (and I need an **ellipsoid**).

Any ideas?

Comment: You have not mentioned how the points should be sampled inside the volume. Should it just be primitive cubic?

Comment: "*creates a circle only in x and y*" yet you plot it as a circle in y and **z**, which I think has confused some of those reading your question, judging by the answers given so far. Wouldn't hurt if you fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

`mask = x*x + y*y <= r*r` gives you a circle, because that's the equation for a circle.

By the same rationale,

`mask = x*x + y*y + z*z <= r*r` should give you a sphere, and

`mask = x*x/(a*a) + y*y/(b*b) + z*z/(c*c) <= r*r` should give you an [ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid#Standard_equation) with principal axes of half-length `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Of course, you'll have to create a `z` array in a way akin to that in which you create your `x` and `y` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

For me the easiest way would be to use the coordinate equations for a sphere and work from there.

```
x = a * cos(u) * cos(v)
y = b * cos(u) * sin(v)
z = c * sin(u)
```

You can construct these coordinates with [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) and then plot.

```
a, b, c = 4, 8, 6
space = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 50)
u, v = np.meshgrid(space)
x = a * np.cos(u) * np.cos(v)
y = b * np.cos(u) * np.sin(v)
z = c * np.sin(u)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z)
fig.show()
```

[image]

[image]

**Update**
To get the interior coordinates of the sphere you would use the mask akin to your example, but with the ellipsoid [implicit equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid#Standard_equation). x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 = 1

```
a, b, c = 4, 8, 6
xs, ys, zs = np.mgrid[-a + 1:a + 1:15j, -b + 1:b + 1:15j, -c + 1:c + 1:15j]
mask = xs**2/(a**2) + ys**2/(b**2) + zs**2/(c**2) <= 1
xs[~mask] = 0
ys[~mask] = 0
zs[~mask] = 0
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs)
fig.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @StuartBuckingham That is a good point. Had not realized you wanted the internal coordinates as well. Let me get back to you on that.

Comment: @StuartBuckingham I updated the answer to include an example of getting the interior points. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your first equations hints axis aligned ellipsoid centered at `(0,0,0)` for such is the easiest way I know of to use scaling to/from sphere. so let:

```
[x ,y ,z ] - ellipsoid (rx,ry,rz)
[x',y',z'] - sphere (r)
```

So the transforms are:

```cpp
// sphere -> ellipsoid
x = x' * rx/r
y = y' * ry/r
z = z' * rz/r

// sphere <- ellipsoid
x' = x * r/rx
y' = y * r/ry
z' = z * r/rz
```

The `(rx,ry,rz)` are the radiuses of ellipsoid (in your case `rx=ry`) and `r` is any nonzero radius of the sphere (for example `r=1.0`)

So the test for inside ellipsoid boils down to this:

```cpp
// scale constants
sx = 1/rx
sy = 1/ry
sz = 1/rz
// condition for inside ellipsoid
x*x*sx*sx + y*y*sy*sy + z*z*sz*sz <= 1.0
```